# can we manage multiple shopify key in one application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

We want to use multiple Shopify API keys in one shopify rails application and switch these API key run time.
We are working on to increase API call by help to multiple API calls. Because of each API key have some limitation calls like 40 call at time.

Comment: Are you looking for multiple API keys or more API calls. You can connect with shopify member to resolve this .